# Sorting Vectors: how to have the boolian function accept a third variable

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I am trying to sort vectors by using:

```
sort(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(),rankComboEnergy);
```

However, I have an additional term (FE_scale) in the boolean expression, which I'd like to vary, depending on the command-line arguments.

```
bool rankComboEnergy(Coordinates2 first, Coordinates2 second) {
    return (first.Energy + FE_scale*first.FEnergy < second.Energy + FE_scale*second.FEnergy);
}
```

I tried a few different things, but am not having much luck.

Comment: Use a lambda function and capture `FE_scale`.

Comment: I'm using c++ compiler which is quite old. I'm not sure if this is supported in gcc 5.4.0?

Comment: @Rubber_duck The alternative to using a lambda on legacy compilers is to define a functor, a `class` type with `operator()`. You would add your extra parameter as a data member for that functor.

Comment: @Rubber_duck GCC 5.4 support old outdated versions of C++ like C++11 and C++14 no problem.  That includes full support for simple lambda captures like what you'll want to use.

Answer (score 3):

Use a lambda-expression! GCC 5.4 supports lambdas with `-std=c++11` flag.

```
float FE_scale = whatever;

sort(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), [=](const Coordinates2 &first, const Coordinates2 &second)
{
    return (first.Energy + FE_scale*first.FEnergy < second.Energy + FE_scale*second.FEnergy);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
struct MySort
{
  double FE_Scale;
  MySort(double f) :FE_Scale(f) {}
  bool operator() (const Coordinates2 & first, const Coordinates2 & second)
  {
    return first.Energy + FE_Scale*first.FEnergy < second.Energy + FE_Scale*second.FEnergy;
  }
};

//...

std::sort(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), MySort(10));
```